# LINQ to SQL where clause returning zero

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When I run this query

```
var query = from a in db.commentsTable 
            select a;
```

it returns the correct amount of results but when I run this query

```
var query = from a in db.commentsTable 
            where a.UserId == userId 
            select a;
```

it returns 0, even though it should return 33. This is the only query that is not working. I do the same with another list and it works fine. Is the where clause causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

Operator `where` does not cause problems. It simply gets translated into SQL clause `WHERE`. So you will have generated query which looks like:

```
SELECT [t0].[UserId], [t0].[Foo], [t0].[Bar] -- other fields from entity
FROM [dbo].[commentsTable] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[UserId] = @p0
```

No magic. If you have zero entities as result, then there is no records in database which have `[UserId]` field equal to value of passed parameter `p0`.

Set a breakpoint on this query and verify value of `userId` which you are passing. Also verify which database you are connected to, and check if you have records which exactly match value of `userId`.

Comment: You are bang on. The problem was where the ids where getting added. Thanks for the response.